# Does Visual Studio 2008 support custom HTTP symbol server?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have an internal symbol server that works well with Visual Studio 2010. At client side, I set environment variable:

```
set _NT_SYMBOL_PATH=SRV*d:\NlsSymbols*http://symsrv.dev.nls/websymbols
```

and VS2010 IDE happily recognize it and draw PDB files from that address(address prefix) to my local folder.

However, VS2008 does not seems to work with this.

No matter I set `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH=` or assign a URL in Options -> Debugging -> Symbols, I can never see VS2008 trying to fetch from my URL.

[image]

[image]

I'd like to know whether VS2008 really support this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, VS2008 supports it.

It was my fault. I forgot to push my PDBs to the server symsrv.dev.nls. After pushing them with symstore.exe, things go right.

A small flaw of VS2005~2010 IDE is that its "Symbol Load Information" dialog does not display HTTP access activity, so we cannot easily know whether it access the right http address. Visual Studio 2013 (maybe from VS2012) fix this problem so we benefit a lot from it.

[image]